# Не отображаются корректно страницы плагина woocommerce (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

в чем собственно заключается моя проблема? У меня не отображаются страницы плагина. Например: Корзина, Магазин, Мой аккаунт, Оформление заказа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все что у меня отображается это содержимое index.php, а именно только:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Для главной страницы я сделал отдельный шаблон для страницы и создал саму страницу. И настроил чтобы она была главной.

**Проблема заключается в том**, что на моей теме данные страницы не отображаются корректно, т.е. на них отображается только header и footer. А на стандартных темах все отображается корректно. Что я делаю не так?

P.s. Я пытался нагуглить решение, но что-то ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: Я почитал в документации подробнее о woocommerce, вообщем у меня не работают шорткоды.

Comment: Много раз уже об этом говорили здесь. Никогда не начинайте знакомство с WordPress с написания собственных тем. Постоянно будете натыкаться на подобного рода проблемы. Берите любую понравившуюся тему из репозитория, делайте от неё дочернюю и постепенно разбирайтесь, что и как работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле function.php нужно было прописать:

```
function woocommerce_support() {
  add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```